# Arrival visa from airport

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, dubai, dxb

I am an Indian with Kuwaiti residence. If I travel by Emirates with my family (wife + two kids) can I get a stop over in Dubai for 3 days without any difficulty (is it easy to obtain a visa to exit Dubai airport)?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to apply for a visa. You can do this through a hotel or tour operator who works in the UAE, or a family member living there. Kuwait nationals don't need visas but Indians do.

33 Countries get visa on arrival and [GCC nationals](http://www.dubaifaqs.com/list-of-gcc-countries.php) don't need to apply for a visa prior to arrival. Some GCC residents who are not nationals are also eligible for a 30 day visa on arrival.

> GCC Residents who are not GCC nationals but who have a high
>   professional status such as company managers, business people,
>   auditors, accountants, doctors, engineers, pharmacists, or employees
>   working in the public sector, their families, drivers and personal
>   staff sponsored by them, are eligible for a non-renewable 30-day visa
>   upon arrival at the approved ports of entry.
>
> Source: [UAE Travel: Tourist: Visa information - UAEinteract](http://www.uaeinteract.com/travel/visas.asp)

If you don't fall into the quote above category then you will have to apply for a visa prior to arrival at Dubai.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE - 2015-MAY-01**

---

The UAE no longer allows visa on arrival for GCC residents. You have to get the visa approved in advance. To this, you need to logon to [this website](https://www.gdrfa.ae/GCCIND/gccLogin.do?userAction=switchToEnglish) and fill in an application.

You'll need to upload copies of your passport and pay the fees online.

---

The information that @Vagish posted is correct, but outdated.

For your wife and kids, their visa eligibility depends on yours.

The following positions are accepted for visa on arrival. These are the English translations, but in your visa the Arabic equivalent will be written:

> 1. Aquatic Specialist
> 2. Statistics Specialist
> 3. Agricultural specialist (General)
> 4. Gardening Specialist
> 5. Medical Analysis Specialist
> 6. Speech Specialist
> 7. Breeding Specialist (Animals/ Birds/ Bees)
> 8. Medical X-ray Specialist
> 9. Nutrition Specialist
> 10. Zoology Specialist
> 11. Psychiatrist
> 12. Lab Specialist
> 13. Sports Medicine Specialist
> 14. Sociologist
> 15. X-Ray Specialist
> 16. Media Specialist
> 17. Customs Specialist
> 18. Medical Therapy Specialist
> 19. Literator
> 20. University Professor
> 21. Media Person
> 22. Secretary or Manager of Library
> 23. Employees at the Embassies in the GCC countries (Except Support Services Jobs)
> 24. Archeological Researcher
> 25. Administrative Researcher
> 26. Legal Researcher
> 27. Professor
> 28. Trader
> 29. Geologist (General)
> 30. Quantity Enumerator
> 31. Referee (sports)
> 32. Finance/Economics Expert
> 33. Legal Expert
> 34. Information Systems Expert
> 35. Diplomat (Members of diplomatic corps)
> 36. Chairman / Executive Director
> 37. President or Director of a University
> 38. Chief Justice
> 39. Head of Prosecution
> 40. President or Director of a Club
> 41. Weather expert
> 42. Earthquakes expert
> 43. Captain of Ship/Cruise/Carrier/Steamship
> 44. Businessman
> 45. Religious person
> 46. Architectural Draftsman
> 47. Business lady
> 48. Executive Secretary
> 49. Journalist
> 50. Pharmacist
> 51. Jeweler
> 52. Army Officer
> 53. Police Officer
> 54. University student
> 55. Physician (All specializations)
> 56. Surgeon (All specializations)
> 57. Veterinary Doctor
> 58. Pilot
> 59. Scientist
> 60. College Dean
> 61. Astronomer
> 62. Artist (Actor, Musician, Composer, Poet, Painter, Singer…..etc)
> 63. Telecom Technician
> 64. Professional Security and Safety Technician
> 65. Medical Equipment Technician
> 66. Control Equipment Technician
> 67. X-ray Technician
> 68. Dental Technician (Fixing)
> 69. Radio or TV Transmission Technician
> 70. Optical Technician
> 71. ECG Technician
> 72. Horse Breeding Technician
> 73. Mining Technician
> 74. Microscopic Technician
> 75. Geology Technician
> 76. Well Drilling Technician
> 77. Pharmaceutical Technician
> 78. Foodstuff Technician
> 79. Ship Maintenance Technician
> 80. Aircraft Maintenance Technician
> 81. Train Maintenance Technician
> 82. Lab Technician
> 83. Aviation Technician
> 84. Physicist
> 85. Judge
> 86. Chemist (All Specializations)
> 87. Player (All sports items in a sports club)
> 88. Author
> 89. Computer Programmer
> 90. Translator
> 91. Accountant / Accounts Verifier / Auditor
> 92. Lecturer
> 93. Lawyer / Advocate
> 94. Economic Analyst
> 95. Systems Analyst
> 96. Operations Analyst
> 97. Director
> 98. Customs Clearer
> 99. Sports Trainer
> 100. Aviation Trainer
> 101. General Professional Trainer
>        (Industrial/Agricultural/Commercial)
> 102. Teacher / Instructor
> 103. Proofreader
> 104. Investment Manager
> 105. Archeological Director
> 106. Research & Studies Director
> 107. Insurance Manager
> 108. Banking Business Manager
> 109. Production Director
> 110. Manager or Director of any government departments or companies
> 111. Administrative Manager
> 112. Broadcasting Manager
> 113. Media Manager
> 114. Regional Director
> 115. Bank Manager
> 116. Commercial Manager
> 117. Marketing Manager
> 118. Television Manager
> 119. Executive Manager or Director
> 120. Cooperative Society Manager
> 121. Accounts Manager
> 122. Cinema Director
> 123. Company or Factory Manager
> 124. Maintenance Manager
> 125. Printing and Publishing Manager
> 126. Hotel Manager
> 127. Finance Manager
> 128. Sales Manager
> 129. Museum Manager
> 130. School Manager
> 131. Farm Manager
> 132. Theatre Manager
> 133. Hospital Manager
> 134. Institute Manager
> 135. Library Manager
> 136. Laboratory Manager
> 137. Marine Transport Manager
> 138. Land Transport Manager
> 139. Air Transport Manager
> 140. Tourism Agency Manager
> 141. TV or Radio Programs Presenter
> 142. Correspondent (Newspaper/Radio/TV)
> 143. Food Controller
> 144. Aircraft Takeoff Controller
> 145. Maritime Controller
> 146. Quality Controller
> 147. Air Controller
> 148. Marine Traffic Controller
> 149. Media Controller
> 150. Road Controller
> 151. Aircraft Landing Controller
> 152. Cruise Ship Guide
> 153. Tourist Guide
> 154. Aviation Guide
> 155. Surveyor
> 156. Assistant Pharmacist
> 157. Assistant Engineer (All specializations)
> 158. Consultant (All types)
> 159. General Supervisor
> 160. Ship Supervisor
> 161. Banker
> 162. Decoration Designer
> 163. TV Cameraman
> 164. Cinema Cameraman
> 165. Press Photographer
> 166. Land Hostess
> 167. Air Hostess
> 168. Program Producer
> 169. Marine Navigator
> 170. Air Navigator
> 171. Male or Female Nurse
> 172. Cinema or Television Producer
> 173. Marketing Representative
> 174. Sports Representative
> 175. Sales Representative
> 176. Procurement Representative
> 177. Administration Coordinator
> 178. Archeological Prospector
> 179. Engineer (All specializations)
> 180. Career Counselor
> 181. Assistant General Manager
> 182. Ship Captain
> 183. Commercial Broker
> 184. Travel or Tourism Agent
> 185. Prosecutor
> 186. Ministry Undersecretary
> 187. Electricity Manager
> 188. Assistant Pilot
> 189. Flight Technician
> 190. Auditor
> 191. Manager (All types)
> 192. Chairman (All types)
> 193. Investor
> 194. Partner
> 195. Bank Official
> 196. Marketing Executive
> 197. Sales Executive
> 198. Special Needs Teacher
> 199. General Specialist
> 200. Consultant (All types)
> 201. Program Designer

You can get a visa on arrival at the airport; these are available from the same counter where you get your money changed.

On August 1st 2014, the visa fee structure was updated and the current rates are:

- Entry Visa for GCC Resident: 200 Dhs
- Entry Visa for GCC Resident Dependants: 150 Dhs

In addition, your (and your dependants’) Kuwait residence must not expire for 6 months and your passport should be valid for 6 months.

Comment: The source of the list is a piece of paper that I have from a colleague who works at the passports division, so there is no online reference to it as far as I know. The fees however, can be found on dubai.ae emirates.com and other sites that with visa on arrival info. They are also mentioned in other answers to similar questions.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid so you typed them all out???